# How do I change the text of the delivery method in the WooCommerce checkout?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

How do I change the text of the delivery method in the checkout? I want to remove the text of the delivery method completely so that only the prices for the delivery methods remain. Through the WooCommerce settings, I failed to leave the delivery methods without a name.

[image: Screenshot of checkout with delivery method text highlighted]

Comment: You change the text of the delivery methods In each shipping method setting directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the label for shipping methods in the WooCommerce cart, you can utilize the `woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label` filter hook. This hook allows you to customize the label based on certain conditions. For example, you can check if the shipping price is greater than zero and then remove the original label and replace it with the shipping price. To implement this, you need to add the provided code snippet to the functions.php file of your active WordPress theme.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'remove_delivery_method_label', 10, 2 );
function remove_delivery_method_label( $label, $method ) {
    if ( $method->cost > 0 ) {
        $label = '';
        $label .= wc_price( $method->cost );
    }
    return $label;
}
```

[image]

[image]